# Is there any relationship between distributions in functional analysis and distributions in differential topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I don't know much functional analysis, and my understanding of distributions in this sense stems mostly from physics(generalized functions that serve as solutions to PDE's), but I am wondering if there is any relation to the distribution in the sense of differential topology (a sub bundle of the tangent bundle). If there is any relationship I would expect it to connect to  Frobenius Theorem but I do not see how.

Comment: I’ve worked extensively with both types and know of no relationship between them.

Comment: Why do you expect any? Similarly, no relation between vector fields and algebraic fields, ring networks and algebraic rings...

Comment: @MoisheKohan It’s not necessarily that I expect any, I was just wondering if their was any deeper reason for them being named the same thing.